# Crear sentencia JPQL WHERE Boolean TRUE

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

Como puedo crear la siguiente sentencia:

`SELECT * FROM "Profiles" WHERE "defaultProfile" = true`

En java utilizando JPQL. Esta es la estructura de la tabla:

```
    Columna     |         Tipo          
----------------+-----------------------
 idProfile      | integer               
 profile        | character varying(32) 
 profileName    | character varying(64) 
 defaultProfile | boolean
```

Se que debo utilizar un CriteriaBuilder:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = currentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<E> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(type);
Root<E> itemRoot = criteriaQuery.from(type);
Predicate predicate = ??
criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
```

Pero no se como crear el Predicate, gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado:

```
    public List<E> search(Class<E> type, String column, Boolean value) {

        Predicate predicate;
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = currentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<E> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(type);
        Root<E> itemRoot = criteriaQuery.from(type);

        if (value) {
            predicate = criteriaBuilder.isTrue(itemRoot.get(column));
        } else {
            predicate = criteriaBuilder.isFalse(itemRoot.get(column));
        }

        criteriaQuery.where(predicate);

        return currentSession().createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
    }
```